# How to automatically open URL after clicking button and executing PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a Joomla website and I am trying to automatically open a modal window with a web page whose parameters are passed in the URL.

The website capability goes like this: A trip leader looks up a trip and he can schedule to lead that trip by clicking on a button.  When the button is clicked I have working Php code that saves the trip data to a calendar database and retrieves the id number of the row. The next step is to edit the entry in the calendar component after passing the information in the URL.  I created the correct URL in a Php variable but I am stuck on how to automatically open a modal window with the page for editing .

Here is some of the code I have:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Lead This Trip" />
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {...code to save data to calendar}
?>
```

At the end I have a variable called `$url` which contains the correct URL for opening the modal website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<style>
/*hide the modal container in the beginning */
#modal {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<!-- this is where your html will populate -->
<div id="modal"></div>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="submit" value="leadteam" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Lead This Trip" />
</form>

<script>
// When the page has loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
      If you need to only have it happen on one or more times, but not every time,
       you can use a selector such as id="whatever" in your form:
       $('#whatever').submit(....etc
       or you want perhaps some but not all forms, use class="whatever" in your form:
       $('.whatever').submit(....etc
    */
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        // prevent the natural submission of the form
        e.preventDefault();
        // create an ajax instance
        $.ajax({
            /*
               This is the where your edit page is located
               If you were to use different forms, you can use the 
               attr in jquery to grab the action="/whatever.php" in the form
               url: $(this).attr('action'),
               This will allow you to use this same code without copy pasting
               but will then allow for any the forms in your site
             */
            url: '<?php $url ?>',
            // This function turns your submission to a post string
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            // Sends as a post
            type: 'post',
            // If the ajax is successful
            success: function(response) {
                // Fade in the modal window
                $('#modal').fadeIn(function() {
                    // Populate with the content on your edit page
                    $(this).html(response);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the relevant code I pasted into my Php file.

Comment: You may want to try using a AJAX for this instead of just PHP.

Comment: Can I run the PHP code I have already created inside the ajax container?  I do not want the php code (added to an existing Joomla PHP file) to run unless the button is clicked.  The idea behind the modal popup is to provide a window in which the user can specify a time and date for leading the trip.

Comment: Yeah all your existing work will still work, you may just have to fix some styles

Comment: I turned my PHP code into a function called "lead_trip" which returns the variable $url containing the URL.  The URL looks like this for now (while I test locally) http://localhost/index.php/trip-calendar?task=edit&viewid=1&format=html&eid=7072&tmpl=component where would this appear in the code?  In other words where would I call the function and resolve the URL variable $url?

Comment: Ok so how Ajax works is you click the submit button in the form, the JavaScript cancels the reload of the the page, then the page that contains your team leader form loads into the modal div. it's basically like loading the other page in a browser except it loads the page into a a container like a div or span, whatever

Comment: So the url in the JavaScript is a separate page that contains the full form

Comment: I can't get the URL data into into 'url' since the script cannot resolve the Php variable $url (I am not familiar enough with Javascript yet but a Php echo does not work).  The URL is a separate stand alone page.

Comment: There is other Javascript being used on the page.  Could that be conflicting?

Comment: Hard to say but probably not. When you do console.log(response); its populated?

Comment: I just tried it again and now when I click the button I get a repeat of the current webpage within the page not in a modal window.  Something seems to be working but not right.

Comment: You have to have two pages. This page and the page that has the form so the url should not be the same url as the page you are loading it into

Comment: But shouldn't the new page appear as an overlay popup on the current page?  I tried changing 'url' to www.google.com but it still shows the current page again.

Comment: Well that is up to you to make it overlay with style sheets.

Comment: Did you had a look at my Answer (jQuery UI Dialog)?

Comment: I thank you for your help and patience.  The problem is I was not specifying the URL correctly and ajax defaults to displaying the current page.  I just need to figure out how to set the ajax url: to a variable and then pass the value of the Php variable to it.  I suppose the pop up thing not happening has something to do with style sheets which I can work out later.  I have not looked too closely at your answer yet KIMB as this one seems promising.

Comment: Is the url you are using dynamic? Like does it have to be dynamic?

Comment: Yes. the Php code creates it and then saves it to a fixed variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open by click a smaller new window with the URL.

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="popup" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $url; ?>', 'popup', 'width=900px,height=500px,top=20px,left=20px'); return false;">Open modal Window</a>
```

If you don't want to use such a Popup, you can use the JQuery UI Dialog widget and an AJAX query.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display: none;">
  Loading ...
</div>

<script>
 function openModal(){
    var modalurl = "<?php echo $url; ?>";
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    $( "#dialog" ).load( modalurl  );
  }
</script>

  <button onclick="openModal();">Open Modal</button>
```

See https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ and http://api.jquery.com/load/

And an example here https://jsfiddle.net/t1d35ekk/

I don't know if the modal windows is the right thing for you, if you want to tell the Browser to open an new URL using PHP, you can set a header:

```
header( 'Location: '.$url  );
die;
```

**Edit:**

Maybe I understand something wrong, so I have changed the code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Trip" style="display: none;">
  Loading ...
</div>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="leadteam" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Lead This Trip" />
</form>

<script>
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
         height: 400,
         minWidth:400,
         close: function( event, ui ) {
             window.location.href = "url to open on close";
         }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
              $( "#dialog" ).html(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with this code is my Php code which saves the trip to the database and generates the trip schedule edit URL does not get activated.

Comment: I added some code from Rasclatt to my jQuery UI Dialog solution. I hope it will work now.

Comment: Your code is now working.  Strange that in Rasclatt's code when I tried url: '<?php echo $url; ?>' it did not work.  How can I change the size of the popup window?  Can I load another webpage after the modal window is closed to prevent double posting? And can the background page be a dark translucent?

Comment: I added some code and have a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/ for further infomation. You can design you own theme for the Dialog online at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/. Just include the CSS file from the download zip file to your page (instead of //code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.  Your revised code worked as expected for a few times.  Now something odd is going on with the url in the ajax code (similar issue to Rasclatt's code) where I can see the correct url for a fraction of a second and then it defaults to the current page in the modal window - very frustrating.

Comment: For me it sounds as that there is something like a redirect. But I can't figure out where or why.

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed an ajax delay because it takes longer to save the data to the calendar and generate the URL than it does for ajax to try and display it.  All works now.  Thanks to you both.

Comment: One more question if I may - where is the best place to put the timeout?

Comment: Play a bit around and search a placee where it works.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use ajax to accomplish this:

```
<!-- You need the jQuery library-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<style>
/*hide the modal container in the beginning */
#modal {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<!-- this is where your html will populate -->
<div id="modal"></div>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="leadteam" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Lead This Trip" />
</form>
<script>
// When the page has loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
      If you need to only have it happen on one or more times, but not every time,
       you can use a selector such as id="whatever" in your form:
       $('#whatever').submit(....etc
       or you want perhaps some but not all forms, use class="whatever" in your form:
       $('.whatever').submit(....etc
    */
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        // prevent the natural submission of the form
        e.preventDefault();
        // create an ajax instance
        $.ajax({
            /*
               This is the where your edit page is located
               If you were to use different forms, you can use the 
               attr in jquery to grab the action="/whatever.php" in the form
               url: $(this).attr('action'),
               This will allow you to use this same code without copy pasting
               but will then allow for any the forms in your site
             */
            url: '/leadtrip.php',
            // This function turns your submission to a post string
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            // Sends as a post
            type: 'post',
            // If the ajax is successful
            success: function(response) {
                // Fade in the modal window
                $('#modal').fadeIn(function() {
                    // Populate with the content on your edit page
                    $(this).html(response);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the code in a jsfiddle [link] https://jsfiddle.net/86470wo3/6/ [/link] and it appears to work right, however, when I copied it into my Php file clicking on "Lead This Trip" does not open the modal window.  My Php code does get executed though.

Comment: Can you pst an edit to you question and show wahat you have so far?